# Install libapache-mod-fastcgi on RPi 2

Tags: pi-2, web-server, apache-httpd

I'm trying to make working Seafile accessible via HTTPS (locally), following [this guide](https://putokaz.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/install-seafile-on-raspian-raspberry-pi/), but I can't install `libapache-mod-fastcgi`, which is why restarting Apache2 finally fails, as `FastCGIExternalServer` is not available.

Other tutorials mention that I could install `libapache-mod-fastcgi` like this:

```
sudo apt-get -b source libapache-mod-fastcgi
sudo dpkg -i libapache2-mod-fastcgi*.deb
```

But that fails with `E: Unable to find a source package for libapache-mod-fastcgi`

Is there any other way making FastCGIExternalServer available on my RPi2?

**edit:**

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

results in

```
E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate
```

Yet, upon inspection of my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I saw that 
`deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi` was commented, so I couldn't use `apt-get source`

Now I was able to install `libapache-mod-fastcgi`:

[This website](https://raspberry-hosting.com/en/faq/how-install-apache2-php-fpm-raspberry-pi) gave me the following:

```
apt-get install debhelper dpatch libtool cdbs libapr1-dev apache2-threaded-dev
```

Yet building failed again, the I ran:

```
apt-get build-dep libapache-mod-fastcgi
```

Now:

```
sudo apt-get -b source libapache-mod-fastcgi
sudo dpkg -i libapache2-mod-fastcgi*.deb
```

seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

Comment: I understand and that was my first approach. I should have mentioned this in the OP.. It results in: `E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 0):

try the following maybe

https://raspberryserver.blogspot.nl/2013/02/installing-lamp-with-fastcgi-php-fpm.html

sources
https://manual.seafile.com/deploy/https_with_apache.html
httpxx://manual.seafile.com/deploy/deploy_with_apache.html

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In fact we're [enforcing this policy](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538): please edit so that the answer stands on its own should the link break in the future. If it is not edited within 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki.